# How to select a cell with a null value?

Tags: c#, datagridview

With a `DefaultView.RowFilter` I select data in a `DataGridView` (`DataTable`).
I load the distinct values from a column into a `TreeView` and then check the `Item`s to filter. The checked `Item`s make the filter.
Like this filter:

```
STREET IN ('A_STREET','B_STREET','C_STREET')
```

This works fine.

But when you check a empty `TreeView` node because in my `DataColumn` there are empty cells then the filter will be:

```
STREET IN ('A_STREET','B_STREET','')
```

This does not work.
How can I filter on empty cells in a `DataTable` with the `DefaultView.RowFilter`?

Comment: Do you want to prevent the datarows that are null from returning on your query or prevent something from using those null rows? Or are you trying to select rows that are null?

Comment: You wrote "This does not work" - what are the expected\actual result from the last query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IN()` condition doesn't work with `NULL` as you discovered. To do so, you'll have to add another condition:

```
DefaultView.RowFilter = "STREET IN('A_STREET','B_STREET') OR STREET IS NULL OR STREET = ''"
```

Alternatively you can use the `ISNULL()` function:

```
DefaultView.RowFilter = "STREET IN('A_STREET','B_STREET') OR ISNULL(STREET, '') = ''"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you could consider, is that upon porting the data from your database to your server, you could convert the nulls to empty strings, like so:

For SQL Server, instead of putting `STREET` in your query string, it would be:

```
IFNULL(STREET, '') AS STREET
```

For Oracle, instead of putting `STREET` in your query string, it would be:

```
NVL(STREET) STREET
```

I wouldn't recommend it with numeric data, but its probably fine with strings and simplifies your application code.